# Don't want kundera logs in my application logs

Tags: xml, persistence, slf4j, logback, kundera

I want to disable Kundera's log in my custom log file, essentially, I don't want to see Kundera's logs at all. The Kundera's PersistenceProperties interface doesn't have any Constant to disable logging.

I have my persistence xml like this.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="rdb">
<provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>
<class>com.rakuten.points.persistence.entities.Geography</class>
    <class>com.rakuten.points.persistence.entities.GrantPointSummary</class>
    <class>com.rakuten.points.persistence.entities.MemberPointSummary</class>
    <class>com.rakuten.points.persistence.entities.PointDate</class>
    <class>com.rakuten.points.persistence.entities.PointValue</class>
    <class>com.rakuten.points.persistence.entities.Reason</class>
    <class>com.rakuten.points.persistence.entities.Redemption</class>
    <class>com.rakuten.points.persistence.entities.Service</class>
    <class>com.rakuten.points.persistence.entities.Settlement</class>
    <class>com.rakuten.points.persistence.entities.State</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="kundera.nodes" value="localhost" />
        <property name="kundera.port" value="9160" />
        <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="LS" />
        <property name="kundera.dialect" value="cassandra" />
        <property name="kundera.show.query" value="false" />
        <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class"
            value="com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClientFactory" />
        <property name="kundera.ddl.auto.prepare" value="update" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My logback.xml is like this:

```
<configuration>
<property resource="resource.properties" />
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
<file>${LOG_HOME}/RPoints.log</file>
<encoder>
   <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{15}#%line%msg%n</pattern>
 </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="debug">
<appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

By the way, I know the work-around for this, that is to change the logback xml as shown below

```
<configuration>
     <property resource="resource.properties" />
     <logger name="<My classes>" level="DEBUG" />
     <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
     <file>${LOG_HOME}/RPoints.log</file>
     <encoder>
         <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{15}#%line
            %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

For me the above is a workaround and not an actual solution.

I am getting the below logs in my custom log file, I want to avoid them. Please tell me how to do that:

```
15:23:28.927 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] INFO  c.i.k.p.EntityManagerFactoryImpl#130 Loading Core
15:23:28.930 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] INFO  c.i.k.l.CoreLoader#41 Loading Kundera Core Metdata ...
15:23:28.933 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] INFO  c.i.k.p.EntityManagerFactoryImpl#654 Loading Persistence Unit MetaData For Persistence Unit(s) ruleengine.
15:23:28.937 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] INFO  c.i.k.c.PersistenceUnitConfiguration#77 Loading Metadata from persistence.xml ...
15:23:29.095 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] INFO  c.i.k.c.PersistenceUnitConfiguration#94 Finishing persistence unit metadata configuration ...
15:23:29.104 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG c.i.k.c.MetamodelConfiguration#98 Loading Entity Metadata...
```